# Entity Framework POCO entity template : format property names

Tags: entity-framework, t4

properties in the database are all in small case and use underscore for word separation. E.g.:

```
customer_order_id
```

I want the property names to conform to my PropertyNameCodingConvention, i.e.: `customer_order_id -> CustomerOrderId`

I have changed the T4 template to accomplish that but I am curious if there is a solution already available.

Comment: just curious have you looked at custom conventions to accomplish this ? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/10/ef-feature-ctp5-pluggable-conventions.aspx

Comment: Yes, my understanding is those apply to CodeFirst approach, which is opposite to what I am doing, i.e. I have database and need to generate C# code (so it is a 'code last' approach).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires change to the template, but here is how I did it:

1. Add to the end of EntityPoco.tt (right before last closing '#>' tag):

   ```
   private string N(string input) {
       return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, 
           "(?:_|^)([a-z])", 
           match => match.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper()).Replace("_", "");
   }
   ```
2. Wrap all the places where a property name is being output (6 total, see code below).

Here is a complete text:

```
<#
//*********************************************************
//
//    Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved.
//    This code is licensed under the Microsoft Public License.
//    THIS CODE IS PROVIDED *AS IS* WITHOUT WARRANTY OF
//    ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING ANY
//    IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
//    PURPOSE, MERCHANTABILITY, OR NON-INFRINGEMENT.
//
//*********************************************************
#>
<#@ template language="C#" debug="false" hostspecific="true"#>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#><#@
 output extension=".cs"#><#

CodeGenerationTools code = new CodeGenerationTools(this);
MetadataLoader loader = new MetadataLoader(this);
CodeRegion region = new CodeRegion(this, 1);
MetadataTools ef = new MetadataTools(this);

string inputFile = @"PSI.Entities.edmx";
EdmItemCollection ItemCollection = loader.CreateEdmItemCollection(inputFile);
string namespaceName = code.VsNamespaceSuggestion();

EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager fileManager = EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(this);
WriteHeader(fileManager);

foreach (var entity in ItemCollection.GetItems<EntityType>().OrderBy(e => e.Name))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs");
    BeginNamespace(namespaceName, code);
#>
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#><#=code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
{
<#
    var propertiesWithDefaultValues = entity.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is PrimitiveType && p.DeclaringType == entity && p.DefaultValue != null);
    var collectionNavigationProperties = entity.NavigationProperties.Where(np => np.DeclaringType == entity && np.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many);
    var complexProperties = entity.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is ComplexType && p.DeclaringType == entity);

    if (propertiesWithDefaultValues.Any() || collectionNavigationProperties.Any() || complexProperties.Any())
    {
#>
    public <#=code.Escape(entity)#>()
    {
<#
        foreach (var edmProperty in propertiesWithDefaultValues)
        {
#>
        this.<#=N(code.Escape(edmProperty))#> = <#=code.CreateLiteral(edmProperty.DefaultValue)#>;
<#
        }

        foreach (var navigationProperty in collectionNavigationProperties)
        {
#>
        this.<#=N(code.Escape(navigationProperty))#> = new HashSet<<#=code.Escape(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType())#>>();
<#
        }

        foreach (var complexProperty in complexProperties)
        {
#>
        this.<#=N(code.Escape(complexProperty))#> = new <#=code.Escape(complexProperty.TypeUsage)#>();
<#
        }
#>
    }

<#
    }

    var primitiveProperties = entity.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is PrimitiveType && p.DeclaringType == entity);
    if (primitiveProperties.Any())
    {
        foreach (var edmProperty in primitiveProperties)
        {
            WriteProperty(code, edmProperty);
        }
    }

    if (complexProperties.Any())
    {
#>

<#
        foreach(var complexProperty in complexProperties)
        {
            WriteProperty(code, complexProperty);
        }
    }

    var navigationProperties = entity.NavigationProperties.Where(np => np.DeclaringType == entity);
    if (navigationProperties.Any())
    {
#>

<#
        foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
            WriteNavigationProperty(code, navigationProperty);
        }
    }
#>
}

<#
    EndNamespace(namespaceName);
}

foreach (var complex in ItemCollection.GetItems<ComplexType>().OrderBy(e => e.Name))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(complex.Name + ".cs");
    BeginNamespace(namespaceName, code);
#>
<#=Accessibility.ForType(complex)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(complex)#>
{
<#
    var complexProperties = complex.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is ComplexType && p.DeclaringType == complex);
    var propertiesWithDefaultValues = complex.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is PrimitiveType && p.DeclaringType == complex && p.DefaultValue != null);

    if (propertiesWithDefaultValues.Any() || complexProperties.Any())
    {
#>
    public <#=code.Escape(complex)#>()
    {
<#
        foreach (var edmProperty in propertiesWithDefaultValues)
        {
#>
        this.<#=N(code.Escape(edmProperty))#> = <#=code.CreateLiteral(edmProperty.DefaultValue)#>;
<#
        }

        foreach (var complexProperty in complexProperties)
        {
#>
        this.<#=N(code.Escape(complexProperty))#> = new <#=code.Escape(complexProperty.TypeUsage)#>();
<#
        }
#>
    }

<#
    }

    var primitiveProperties = complex.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is PrimitiveType && p.DeclaringType == complex);
    if (primitiveProperties.Any())
    {
        foreach(var edmProperty in primitiveProperties)
        {
            WriteProperty(code, edmProperty);
        }
    }

    if (complexProperties.Any())
    {
#>

<#
        foreach(var edmProperty in complexProperties)
        {
            WriteProperty(code, edmProperty);
        }
    }
#>
}

<#
    EndNamespace(namespaceName);
}

if (!VerifyTypesAreCaseInsensitiveUnique(ItemCollection))
{
    return "";
}

fileManager.Process();

#>
<#+
void WriteHeader(EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager fileManager)
{
    fileManager.StartHeader();
#>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

<#+
    fileManager.EndBlock();
}

void BeginNamespace(string namespaceName, CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    CodeRegion region = new CodeRegion(this);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(namespaceName))
    {
#>
namespace <#=code.EscapeNamespace(namespaceName)#>
{
<#+
        PushIndent(CodeRegion.GetIndent(1));
    }
}


void EndNamespace(string namespaceName)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(namespaceName))
    {
        PopIndent();
#>
}
<#+
    }
}

void WriteProperty(CodeGenerationTools code, EdmProperty edmProperty)
{
    WriteProperty(Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
                  code.Escape(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
                  code.Escape(edmProperty),
                  code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
                  code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)));
}

void WriteNavigationProperty(CodeGenerationTools code, NavigationProperty navigationProperty)
{
    var endType = code.Escape(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType());
    WriteProperty(PropertyVirtualModifier(Accessibility.ForProperty(navigationProperty)),
                  navigationProperty.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many ? ("ICollection<" + endType + ">") : endType,
                  code.Escape(navigationProperty),
                  code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(navigationProperty)),
                  code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(navigationProperty)));
}

void WriteProperty(string accessibility, string type, string name, string getterAccessibility, string setterAccessibility)
{
#>
    <#=accessibility#> <#=type#> <#=N(name)#> { <#=getterAccessibility#>get; <#=setterAccessibility#>set; }
<#+
}

string PropertyVirtualModifier(string accessibility)
{
    return accessibility + (accessibility != "private" ? " virtual" : "");
}

bool VerifyTypesAreCaseInsensitiveUnique(EdmItemCollection itemCollection)
{
    var alreadySeen = new Dictionary<string, bool>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    foreach(var type in itemCollection.GetItems<StructuralType>())
    {
        if (!(type is EntityType || type is ComplexType))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (alreadySeen.ContainsKey(type.FullName))
        {
            Error(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "This template does not support types that differ only by case, the types {0} are not supported", type.FullName));
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            alreadySeen.Add(type.FullName, true);
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private string N(string input) {
    return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "(?:_|^)([a-z])", match => match.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper()).Replace("_", "");
}
#>
```

Comment: It is important to note that if POCO objects are used the property to entities (in Conceptual Model) mapping is done based on property names, therefore _just_ changing property names will not work. You also need to change Conceptual Model entity property names OR specify mapping (POCO->Entity) using attributes OR changing property names in Conceptual Model (CSL)

Answer (score 1):

In EDMX file, you have two different schema, and one mapping schema. What you can do is, you can modify conceptual schema and change property names, however refreshing EDMX might erase this information. But by doing this, you will not have to change template at all.

Comment: You are right, that is an option but it has few significant drawbacks: 1. you are right about refreshing EDM. 2. changing the names manually is not fun. 3. I can't change names using regex (not in VS).